# Order of group and its elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ is a noncommutative group, $|G|=6$, then in $G$ there exists at least one element $x$ of order $3$. Prove and give the opposite example.

Comment: What doe you mean with "opposite example"?

Comment: counterexample*

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it should be "prove or give a counter-example".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $G$ does not have any element of order $3$ then by Lagrange every element has order $2$ (apart from $1_G$)

So $g^2=1 \quad \forall g \in G$. Then

$ab=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba$

EDIT

There is no element of order $6$: if $h\in G $ of order $6$ then $|<h>|=|G|\Rightarrow G=<h> $ , cyclic group so it is a commutative group.

Comment: You should explain why there is no element of order $6$.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! (I thought it was obvious but it is indeed necessary to mention)

Comment: I thought it might be not so obvious for beginners.